# Convert keyboard layout from AZERTY to QWERTY

Tags: java, keyboard, locale

I'm programming in Java using a French machine with an AZERTY keybord. I like to type text with a certain character, the colon, `test: hello`. When I launch the test, only `test` is displayed. Are there ways in Java to convert the colon `:` to the QWERTY equivalent?

Comment: You have to distinct between writing the text and running you code. Can you input the character `:` ? If so it has nothing to do with your keyboard settings. If you run your code and you don't get the expected output, you should post your code so that we can help you. And all characters are UTF-8 in Java so it has nothing to do with what type of keyboard you use (only the keys are at different postitions).

Comment: Yes GrzegorzOledzki,I mean
 QWERTY

Answer (score 0):

If you are use `JSE` ,you can use this method :

```
changLangKeyboardInEN(){
            jTextField.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("en", "US"));
            boolean isOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);

            if (!isOn) {
                try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
```